# What's the next two numbers in the series?

Tags: number-sequence

What's the next two numbers and how did you get to the answer?

The series:

> 2, 4, 4, 8, 12, 16, 48, 64, 288, 448, 1728

Hint 1

> The first two digits are the beginning of the sequence and were not created by the logic of the sequence.

Hint 2

> He was a no one
>  A zero, zero
>  Now he's a hot shot
>  He's a hero

Comment: *pokes the second hint box, a bit, but nothing rattles out*

Comment: Hmm, is "Coming Soon..." some kind of cryptic hint to confuse us, or is the second hint being added soon. ;)

Comment: A few remarks just to save other solvers doing redundant work. First: the sequence is not in OEIS. Second: every term so far is a multiple of the term two before it. Third: the ratios are 2 2 3 2 4 4 6 7 6. Fourth: the sequence 2,4,12,48,288,1728 (i.e., alternate terms from this sequence) is also not in OEIS.

Comment: This puzzle feels Herculean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The next two numbers are

> $3136$ and $15552$.

Reasoning:

> Denote by $f(n)$ the number of $0$s in the binary representation of $n$. For example:
>  $n=4$:   binary representation = $100$;       hence $f(4)=2$
>  $n=8$:   binary representation = $1000$;      hence $f(8)=3$
>  $n=12$:  binary representation = $1100$;      hence $f(12)=2$
>  $n=16$:  binary representation = $1000$;      hence $f(16)=4$
>  $n=48$:  binary representation = $110000$;    hence $f(48)=4$
>  $n=64$:  binary representation = $1000000$;   hence $f(64)=6$
>  $n=288$: binary representation = $100100000$; hence $f(288)=7$
>  $n=448$: binary representation = $111000000$; hence $f(448)=6$
>  $n=1728$: binary representation = $11011000000$; hence $f(1728)=7$
>  $n=3136$: binary representation = $110001000000$; hence $f(3136)=9$

The recursion is:

> $a_n~=~ a_{n-2}*f(a_{n-1})$

Example:

> $a_3~=~ a_1*f(a_2) ~=~ 2*f(4) ~=~   2*2 ~=~ 4$
>  $a_4~=~ a_2*f(a_3) ~=~ 4*f(4) ~=~   4*2 ~=~ 8$
>  $a_5~=~ a_3*f(a_4) ~=~ 4*f(8) ~=~   4*3 ~=~12$
>  $a_6~=~ a_4*f(a_5) ~=~ 8*f(12) ~=~  8*2 ~=~16$
>  $a_7~=~ a_5*f(a_6) ~=~ 12*f(16) ~= 12*4 ~=~48$
>  $a_8~=~ a_6*f(a_7) ~=~ 16*f(48) ~=~16*4 ~=~64$
>  $a_9~=~ a_7*f(a_8) ~=~ 48*f(64) ~=~48*6 ~=~288$
>  $a_{10}~=~ a_8*f(a_9)    ~=~  64*f(288) ~=~  64*7 ~=~ 448$
>  $a_{11}~=~ a_9*f(a_{10}) ~=~ 288*f(448) ~=~ 288*6 ~=~ 1728$
>  $a_{12}~=~ a_{10}*f(a_{11}) ~=~ 448*f(1728) ~=~ 448*7 ~=~ 3136$
>  $a_{13}~=~ a_{11}*f(a_{12}) ~=~ 1728*f(3136) ~=~ 1728*9 ~=~ 15552$

Comment: Ah, I just had it too. Well done!

Answer (score 10):

**Edit:** This is an old answer based on the first $10$ entries in the sequence.

I think the next two numbers in the sequence are

> $2016$ and $4032$

Reasoning

> For a number $x$ define $i(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ 
>  and define $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor - \lceil i(x) \rceil$
> As per the hint, set $a_1 = 2$ and $a_2 = 4$. 
>  Then, for $n>2$, the $n$th term in the sequence is given by 
> $$ a_n = a_{n-2} * f(\log_2 (a_{n-1})) $$

Example

> $a_9 = 288$ and $a_{10} = 448$. 
>  $\log_2(a_{10}) = \log_2(448) = 8.8073549\ldots$ 
>  $ \Rightarrow f(\log_2(448)) = 8 - 1 = 7$ 
>  Hence, $a_{11} = 288 * 7 = 2016$

Comment: Another way to define your function f: f(x) = x if x is an integer, otherwise f(x) = floor(x)-1.

Comment: You're math and logic are sound, it matches the given numbers but it is not the next two in my sequence. Maybe I haven't given enough numbers to differentiate the two sequences. I will add another number. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: @TheReffered given any finite sequence, an infinite amount of sequences can be made to fit it.

Comment: @KoA What's the protocol for sequences then? Should I skip two numbers in my sequence and give one on the other side? Or just mark this answer as correct?

Comment: @TheReffered as long as the 'rule' you've come up with is clearly the most correct, then you don't have to do anything - generally with sequence questions it's best to leave another hint as to what the sequence is, as you have :)